# Is there any plugin for Visual Studio 12 to automated scale images?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, windows-store

In Win 8 (Metro) Apps you have the possibility to create different scaled images for high or low resolution ([more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)). I would like to have a VS Plugin or build-in function that scales down the images, so I don't have to do it by my own. Is there any build in function in Visual Studio that I missed or do anybody knows a good extension for this?

Basically I will just create the 180% scale and the extension should generate the 140%, 100% and 80 % scale images automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale your images to different resolutions, i would recommend you have a look at [Guidelines for scaling to screens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx)

ViewBox is the better solution to make the app fit for all resolutions.